Theorem title going out of margin
I am trying to use the theorem environment but I have a long title name associated with the theorem, causing it to continue out of the margin and the page. Is there a specific command I can use to fix this please?
\begin{theorem}[Universal Approximation Theorem for Feedforward Neural Networks]
  Text here
\end{theorem}



Welcome to TeX.SE please provide MWE from \documentclass to \end{document} as always

It looks like you're employing the ntheorem package.
Assuming you can't or don't want to switch to using the amsthm package, and assuming further that you're using the default, i.e., plain, theorem style, I suggest you insert the following code chunk between \usepackage{ntheorem} and \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}:
\makeatletter
\renewtheoremstyle{plain}%
  {\item{\theorem@headerfont ##1 ##2\theorem@separator}\hskip\labelsep\relax}
  {\item{\theorem@headerfont ##1 ##2 (##3)\theorem@separator}\hskip\labelsep\relax}
\makeatother



\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage{ntheorem}
\makeatletter
\renewtheoremstyle{plain}% the default theorem style
  {\item{\theorem@headerfont ##1 ##2\theorem@separator}\hskip\labelsep\relax}
  {\item{\theorem@headerfont ##1 ##2 (##3)\theorem@separator}\hskip\labelsep\relax}
\makeatother
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Universal Approximation Theorem for Feedforward Neural Networks]
Let the activation function $h(\cdot)$ be chosen in such a way that it is a discriminatory function. Furthermore, suppose that \dots
\end{theorem}

\end{document}


Remark: My answer was inspired in part by the Oct 2012 posting Line break in theorem header. The main change lies in adapting the answer to work with the plain theorem style instead of the break theorem style.
